# How to fill gaps between dated entries in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a set of dated records in @dailylogs.

Lets say I have a row(dailylog) for the 1st of the month.  When I add a new record for say the 15th how can I add a blank entry for each day in between please so that every day of the month has an entry.

I can work out the number of days between the two dates so some sort of loop through @dailylogs to check if the days in between have an entry....but I just cant't work it out.

Thanks

Comment: I did it like this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `Date` objects is very simple.

```
require 'date'

from = Date.new(2017, 1, 1)
to   = Date.new(2017, 1, 5)

from.step(to).to_a
 => [#<Date: 2017-01-01 ((2457755j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2017-01-02 ((2457756j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2017-01-03 ((2457757j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2017-01-04 ((2457758j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2017-01-05 ((2457759j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this in the end:

```
x = 1
day_range.times do
  if Dailylog.search_day(date_today.month, date_today.year, x, user).blank?
    create_date = DateTime.new(date_today.year, date_today.month, x)
    Dailylog.create(date: create_date, miles: "0", locations: "nil", user_id: user)
  end
  x+=1
end
```

which used:

```
def Dailylog.search_day(month, year, day, user)
where("cast(strftime('%m', date) as int) = ?", month)
.where("cast(strftime('%Y', date) as int) = ?", year)
.where("cast(strftime('%d', date) as int) = ?", day)
.where("user_id = ?", user)
```

end

It works but as a beginner happy to be corrected if can be done better.

Thx.